# Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Tags: php, arrays, explode

The Script:

```
<?php

    $tqs = "SELECT * FROM `table_two`";
    $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tqr);
    $thearray[] = $row['some_text_id'];

    // Prints e.g.: Array ( [0] => 164, 165, 166 )
    print_r($thearray);

    echo "<br/><br/>";
    echo "<br/><br/>";

    $thearray = explode(", ", $thearray);
    print_r($thearray);

?>
```

I have the following entry in one row of the column *"some_text_id"*:

```
164, 165, 166
```

I am looking to "explode" this by the comma and have it stored in an array, so I can select the numbers individually, e.g.:

```
myarray[0], myarray[1], myarray[2]
```

Though I am getting the following error message:

> Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in ... (points to the explode function)

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: If you look closely the examples are all with "strings", none with arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skip the part where you put the database results into an array. It's completely unnecessary:

```
<?php

    $tqs = "SELECT * FROM `table_two`";
    $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tqr);

    // Prints e.g.: 164, 165, 166
    print_r($row['some_text_id']);

    echo "<br/><br/>";
    echo "<br/><br/>";

    $thearray = explode(", ", $row['some_text_id']);
    print_r($thearray);

?>
```